# Delphi - loging all HTTP request

Tags: delphi, http, traffic

I need loging all  HTTP request (from any application).
I have Delphi 7.0.
Anybody know how do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I looked into whether the Indy components could do this but found an old newsgroup response from Remy Lebeau that said:

> If...you want to look at the traffic
>   that other applications are
>   generating, then no, you cannot use
>   Indy for that. That is outside the
>   scope of what Indy is designed for. 
>   You would have to write your own NDIS
>   driver for that kind of capturing.  Or
>   use a third-party sniffer API, such as
>   [WinPCap](http://www.winpcap.org).

Comment: There is even a Delphi wrapper for WinPcap: http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/magmonsock.asp

Answer (score 1):

What about [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/)?

There is also a product called [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  I have found this extremely useful to track down exactly what the Indy components are sending/receiving.  The one drawback is you have to utilize a proxy.  This isn't a problem with Indy components and browsers such as Firefox.  But if you need to capture for all applications you would need to be able to set a proxy for those apps.

Comment: WireShark is successor of Ethereal, and uses WinPcap. So these answers all point to the same...

Answer (score 1):

if you want to go deeper and want pure delphi thing, there is winsock logger program floating around, google might help you ( it hooks winsock apis though).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to write a Delphi app to do it?  Could you use an application like [ethereal](http://www.ethereal.com/)?